# OLTP Sql Server RAID configuration with 10 disks, allocation Unit and disk stripe size

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2, raid

On a new db server I only have 10 disks to play with,

The usage is about a booking every 3-5 seconds, so not high volume, I know compromises have to be made, but my initial thoughts are -

DISK 1 & 2 - RAID 1 - OS
DISKS 3,4,5,6 - RAID 10 - Data, Indexes & TempDB
DISKS 7,8,9,10 - RAID 10 - Logs & Backup

Full backups will take place when there is virtually no traffic on the website so not bothered about the contention with the logs.

disk 3-10 - 8kb  NTFS unit allocation size 
disk 3-10 - 64kb Disk Stripe size

does this seems to be sensible, any other considerations I have omitted ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly there, I'd do;

- 1 & 2 - OS - R1
- 3 - 6 - Data etc - R10
- 7 & 8 - Logs - R1
- 9 & 10 - Backup - R1

You don't need much space for logs, so I'd split the logs and backup - otherwise fine, stripe and block's fine too.

Comment: I would put the tempdb (DB) on the OS discs. If that one starts being used (IO wise) the memory is too small - tempdb tries to avoid actually WRITING to the disc.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want 64k blocks across the board.  SQL does almost all of it's IO in 64k blocks.